# Высота всех блоков, равная большей.

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Вот у меня есть три блока с одним классом .isub. Эти блоки по разному заполнены. Можно ли с помощью jQuery посмотреть, какой блок самый высокий и применить всем блокам с классом .isub  высоту, равную самому высокому блоку?

Comment: а на чистом СSS выравнивание блоков годится?
http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/karkas-verstki/kolonki-ravnoy-visoty.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
   var mh = 0;
   $(".block").each(function () {
       var h_block = parseInt($(this).height());
       if(h_block > mh) {
          mh = h_block;
       };
   });
   $(".block").height(mh);
```

Comment: Что-то не рабоатет

Comment: @inferus-vv вы название класса поменяли?

Comment: Знал, что вы это спросите)) В первую очередь

Comment: стоп. Надо же в DOM обернуть так?

Comment: Все, работает. Спасибо большое. А .each что делает? А то на сайте как то непонятно написано

Comment: @inferus-vv конечно нужно в document.ready обернуть, либо после html добавить этот скрипт. each: http://jquery-docs.ru/utilities/jquery-each/ а по простому это удобная функция для перебора всех элементов массива.

Comment: parseInt() в данном случае - лишнее.

Answer (score 3):

Второй вариант:

```
var mh = Math.max.apply(Math, $('.block').map(function(){  
    return $(this).height();
}).get());
```