# Расположение Div-ов

Tags: html, css

Помогите сделать так чтобы несмотря на количество текста внутри все 4 `div`-а были ровными.

[image: пример]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать их таблицей, если не требуется адаптив и надо именно на html/css.

С помощью JS:
[1 решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/164116/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9)

И ещё один вариант

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.equivalent = function (){
            //запишем значение jQuery выборки к которой будет применена эта функция в локальную переменную $blocks
        var $blocks = $(this),
            //примем за максимальную высоту - высоту первого блока в выборке и запишем ее в переменную maxH
            maxH    = $blocks.eq(0).height(); 

        //делаем сравнение высоты каждого блока с максимальной
        $blocks.each(function(){
            maxH = ( $(this).height() > maxH ) ? $(this).height() : maxH;
            /*
            Этот блок можно записать так:
            if ( $(this).height() > maxH ) {
                maxH = $(this).height();
            }
            */
        });

        //устанавливаем найденное максимальное значение высоты для каждого блока jQuery выборки
        $blocks.height(maxH); 
    }

    //применяем нашу функцию в элементам jQuery выборки - $('.job')
    $('.job').equivalent(); 
});
```

[Источник](https://webcomplex.com.ua/kak-sdelat/jquery-kak-vyrovnyat-bloki-po-vysote.html)

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте для .job:

```
vertical-align: top;
```