# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать блоки одной высоты на flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы все флекс элементы в контейнере были одной высоты? align-items: stretch; дает выравнивание только в рамках одной строки. А мне нужно так: чтобы все элементы в контейнере выравнивались по наибольшему по высоте. При этом контент в них будет динамичный, могут вставить как два слова, так и два абзаца и соответственно высота всех блоков должна подстраиваться по наибольшему. Поэтому фиксированная высота не подойдет. Как это реализовать на флексах? спасибо!

```css
.features-product__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
  
  .features-product__item {
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 25%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
 }
```

```html
                    
                    <div class="features-product__container">
             
                        <div class="features-product__item">
                            <p class="features-product__text">
                                Внезапно, активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира лишь добавляют фракционных разногласий и в равной степени предоставлены сами себе. Задача организации, в особенности же разбавленное изрядной долей эмпатии,
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="features-product__item">
                            <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="features-product__item">
                            <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="features-product__item">
                            <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно, активно развивающиеся</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="features-product__item">
                            <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно, активно развивающиеся</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="features-product__item">
                            <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно, активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира лишь добавляют фракционных разногласий и в равной степени предоставлены сами себе. Задача организации, в особенности же разбавленное изрядной долей эмпатии,</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="features-product__item">
                            <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно, активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира лишь добавляют фракционных разногласий и в равной степени предоставлены сами себе. Задача организации, в особенности же разбавленное изрядной долей эмпатии,</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="features-product__item">
                            <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно, активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира лишь добавляют фракционных разногласий и в равной степени предоставлены сами себе. Задача организации, в особенности же разбавленное изрядной долей эмпатии, рациональное мышление представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки существующих финансовых и административных условий. Не следует, однако, забывать, что современная методология разработки является качественно новой ступенью укрепления моральных ценностей.
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное, только такой вариант:

Этот пример на основе ответа от [lampa](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/164116/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9)

```js
var mh = 0;
$(".features-product__item").each(function() {
  var h_block = parseInt($(this).height());
  if (h_block > mh) {
    mh = h_block;
  };
});
$(".features-product__item").height(mh);
```

```css
.features-product__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.features-product__item {
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 25%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="features-product__container">

  <div class="features-product__item">
    <p class="features-product__text">
      Внезапно, активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира лишь добавляют фракционных разногласий и в равной степени предоставлены сами себе. Задача организации, в особенности же разбавленное изрядной долей эмпатии,
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="features-product__item">
    <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно</p>
  </div>
  <div class="features-product__item">
    <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно</p>
  </div>
  <div class="features-product__item">
    <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно, активно развивающиеся</p>
  </div>
  <div class="features-product__item">
    <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно, активно развивающиеся</p>
  </div>
  <div class="features-product__item">
    <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно, активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира лишь добавляют фракционных разногласий и в равной степени предоставлены сами себе. Задача организации, в особенности же разбавленное изрядной долей эмпатии,</p>
  </div>
  <div class="features-product__item">
    <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно, активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира лишь добавляют фракционных разногласий и в равной степени предоставлены сами себе. Задача организации, в особенности же разбавленное изрядной долей эмпатии,</p>
  </div>
  <div class="features-product__item">
    <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно, активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира лишь добавляют фракционных разногласий и в равной степени предоставлены сами себе. Задача организации, в особенности же разбавленное изрядной долей эмпатии, рациональное мышление представляет собой
      интересный эксперимент проверки существующих финансовых и административных условий. Не следует, однако, забывать, что современная методология разработки является качественно новой ступенью укрепления моральных ценностей.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 2):

Зря вы не смотрите в сторону гридов, они очень удобные, для вашего ответа мне понадобилось 5 минут, чтобы выстроить правильно блоки по [этой статье](https://medium.com/@stasonmars/%D0%B2%D0%B5%CC%88%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-grid-%D0%B2-css-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-220508316f8b), хотя я не был знаком с гридами

```css
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-gap: 10px;
```

Я задал, что это сетка `display: grid`, задал, что высота 1,2,3 линии сетки равна условной единице `1fr 1fr 1fr`, а также ширина `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;` 1,2,3 элемента в сетке равна единице и задал отступы между всеми элементами сетки в 10px `grid-gap: 10px;`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.features-product__container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
  
.features-product__item {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="features-product__container">

    <div class="features-product__item">
        <p class="features-product__text">
            Внезапно, активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира лишь добавляют фракционных разногласий и в равной степени предоставлены сами себе. Задача организации, в особенности же разбавленное изрядной долей эмпатии,
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="features-product__item">
        <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно</p>
    </div>
    <div class="features-product__item">
        <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно</p>
    </div>
    <div class="features-product__item">
        <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно, активно развивающиеся</p>
    </div>
    <div class="features-product__item">
        <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно, активно развивающиеся</p>
    </div>
    <div class="features-product__item">
        <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно, активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира лишь добавляют фракционных разногласий и в равной степени предоставлены сами себе. Задача организации, в особенности же разбавленное изрядной долей эмпатии,</p>
    </div>
    <div class="features-product__item">
        <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно, активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира лишь добавляют фракционных разногласий и в равной степени предоставлены сами себе. Задача организации, в особенности же разбавленное изрядной долей эмпатии,</p>
    </div>
    <div class="features-product__item">
        <p class="features-product__text">Внезапно, активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира лишь добавляют фракционных разногласий и в равной степени предоставлены сами себе. Задача организации, в особенности же разбавленное изрядной долей эмпатии, рациональное мышление представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки существующих финансовых и административных условий. Не следует, однако, забывать, что современная методология разработки является качественно новой ступенью укрепления моральных ценностей.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Так как `align-items` применяется только к текущей flex-строке, Вам необходимо использовать JavaScript для решения такой задачи. Просто нужно при загрузке документа найти все элементы с классом `features-product__item` затем среди них найти высоту самого высокого элемента и задать свойство `height` для этого же класса, равное высоте самого высокого элемента

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!